# How to do Network discovery using UDP broadcast in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to to do network discovery using UDP Broadcast in IOS. I don't know how to do this. Can you give me advice on how to do it?

I want to do like this [tutorial](https://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Cocoa Async Socket

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Below is the code

```
    GCDAsyncUdpSocket *udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![udpSocket enableReusePort:YES error:&error]) 
    {
        return;
    }

    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:8888 error:&error])
    {
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        return;
    }

    error = nil;
    if(![udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error])
    {
    }

    NSData *data = [@"DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_REQUEST" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:@“255.255.255.255” port:8888 withTimeout:10 tag:100];
```

below is the delegate method where you will get response

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
{
     NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSString *msg1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RECV: %@ FROM: %@", msg,[GCDAsyncUdpSocket hostFromAddress:address]];

    if([msg isEqualToString:@"DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_RESPONSE"])
    {
    }
}
```

And if got error while udp socket connection this delegate method will be called

```
- (void)udpSocketDidClose:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RECV: error: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    }
}
```